# ImportError: No module named botocore.session - when running AWS CLI from Rundeck

Tags: python, aws

I can't run AWS CLI commands via Rundeck, from terminall all works fine,
installed boto3,botocore also installed

```
 import sys
import os

if os.environ.get('LC_CTYPE', '') == 'UTF-8':
    os.environ['LC_CTYPE'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
import awscli.clidriver


def main():
    return awscli.clidriver.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

This is what i get on Rundeck UI

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/bin/aws", line 19, in <module>
        import awscli.clidriver
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 17, in <module>
        import botocore.session
    ImportError: No module named botocore.session
```

Answer (score 15):

Managed to get rid of error by

```
pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

then from rundeck interface (commands tab):

```
aws configure set aws_access_key_id default_access_key
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key default_secret_key
aws configure set default.region us-west-2
```

Comment: I've got the error `No matching distribution found for botocore==1.12.26 (from awscli)` using that command...

Comment: using `sudo` in front of `pip ...` fixed my problem